# Kill another thread in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I am running a function `doTask` in another thread like below:

```
NSThread *otherThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                selector:@selector(doTask)
                                                  object:nil];
[otherThread start];

...
-(void)doTask{
   ...
}
```

What is the proper way to kill `otherThread` from current thread?

I know `[otherThread cancel]` only marks the `otherThread` should be killed but not really killing it.

Comment: It's always best to *ask* the other thread to terminate, rather than *tell* it.  It will be much cleaner this way.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how in my case can I ask otherThread to terminate ?

Comment: Unknown; it's depends on the relationship between the classes.

Answer (score 0):

`doTask` needs to check some state somewhere periodically to see if it needs to terminate early.   A simple BOOL is good enough.

```
@interface MyTask:NSObject
@property(atomic) BOOL keepGoing;
@end

@implementation MyTask
- (void) calculate
{
    while(_keepGoing && _workQueueHasStuff) {
        .... process some stuff ....
    }
    if (!_keepGoing) {
         ... early termination ...
    } else {
         ... work queue depleted ...
    }
}
```

---

Or, as S.S said, use the `isCancelled/-cancel` API as intended

---

You cannot kill a thread directly from outside the thread.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `[otherThread cancel]` after invalidating timers, or stopping other time consuming operations that the thread is currently running. If you clean up properly and call cancel it should kill the thread.

Comment: but `exit` is a class method not a instance method in NSThread.

Comment: Stupid, my mistake. What kind of task are you running inside doTask?